# OAM and Sharepoint 2013 integration

Tags: iis, sharepoint, integration, integrate, oam

I'm using Sharepoint server 2013 running on Windows Server 2012R2 and IIS 8.5.
I want to integrate sharepoint 2013 with OAM(Oracle Access Manager) for single sign on purpose. I followed some guides on the internet, but it all use webgate 10g to communicate with OAM server and integrate with sharepoint 2010. I tried to install webgate 10g on IIS 8.5 but it seem doesn't work, maybe compatibility problem. Then i tried install webgate 11g but it doesn't work too.
Here is my event viewer log when i browse the web application that is protected by webgate 11g:
[image]
[image]

And here is my log in oblog in webgate folder:

> 2016/04/27@00:12:30.754000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/en-us/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/fr-fr/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/de-de/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/es-es/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/it-it/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/ja-jp/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/ko-kr/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/zh-cn/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/zh-tw/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.755000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/oblix/lang/pt-br/globalmsg.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:30.858000    8216    5736    INIT    ERROR   0x000003B6  base\oblistrwutil.cpp:225   "Could
>   not read
>   file" filename^e:\oracle\product\11.1.1\as_2\webgate\iis/config/oblog_config.xml
>   2016/04/27@00:12:33.213000    8216    1068    CONNECTIVITY    ERROR   0x0000211E  ..\src\obsocket.cpp:430 "Invalid
>   hostname for OAM Server defined." 
>   2016/04/27@00:12:35.495000    8216    1068    CONNECTIVITY    ERROR   0x0000211E  ..\src\obsocket.cpp:430 "Invalid
>   hostname for OAM Server defined." 
>   2016/04/27@00:12:37.757000    8216    1068    CONNECTIVITY    ERROR   0x0000211E  ..\src\obsocket.cpp:430 "Invalid
>   hostname for OAM Server defined." 
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.016000    8216    1068    CONNECTIVITY    ERROR   0x0000211E  ..\src\obsocket.cpp:430 "Invalid
>   hostname for OAM Server defined." 
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.016000    8216    5736    CONFIG  ERROR   0x00000505  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:747 "ObAccess
>   exception thrown" raw_code^0
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.016000    8216    5736    ACCESS_GATE FATAL   0x00001520  ..\src\iisentry_web_gate.cpp:619    "Exception
>   thrown during WebGate initialization" 
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.017000    8216    5736    ACCESS_GATE FATAL   0x0000182C  ..\src\iisentry_web_gate.cpp:620    "The
>   AccessGate is unable to contact any Access Servers."  raw_code^301
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.017000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.017000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.018000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.018000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.018000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.018000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.018000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204
>   2016/04/27@00:12:40.019000    8216    5736    CONFIG  FATAL   0x0000181C  ..\src\obconfig.cpp:863 "Oracle
>   AccessGate API is not initialized."   raw_code^204

I have a question, On webserver IIS, to communicate with OAM Server i just need to install Webgate or need to be install other components? I'm really confused, please help me, thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install and Configure WebGate on IIS Webserver.

The OAM hostname is either incorrect or not getting resolved from your IIS box.

> 2016/04/27@00:12:33.213000 8216 1068 CONNECTIVITY ERROR 0x0000211E
>   ..\src\obsocket.cpp:430 "Invalid hostname for OAM Server defined."
>   2016/04/27@00:12:35.495000 8216 1068 CONNECTIVITY ERROR 0x0000211E
>   ..\src\obsocket.cpp:430 "Invalid hostname for OAM Server defined."

Answer (score 0):

You must apply BP13 along with the IIS 10g webgate. We have applied patch and it is successfully integrated with Sharepoint 2013 for SSO and WNA.

If any queries revert to me